# How to preserve the value of class properties

Tags: python

```
class A:
    p = 1
    def __init__(self, p=None, **kwargs):
        self.p = p

class B(A):
    p = 2

a = A()
print(a.p)
b = B()
print(b.p)
```

As a more sensible example consider:

```
class Mamal:
    can_fly = False

class Bat(Mamal):
    can_fly = True
```

In the examples above, I would like `1` and `2` be printed. However, it prints `None` for both, though I know why. What is the solution to preserve the default value of classes?

One solution I can think of is:

```
class A:
    p = 1
    def __init__(self, p=None, **kwargs):
        if p: self.p = p
        if q: self.q = q
        ...
```

and if I have many attributes I should do that for all of them!? another minor problem is that the user can't pass None to the class init.

Another solution could be like:

```
class A:
    p = 1
    def __init__(self, p=1, **kwargs):
        self.p = p
        self.q = q
        ...
```

However again if one instantiate b like:

```
b = B()
```

the value of `b.p` would be also `1`, while I expect it to keep `2`.

I use overriding classes attributes much, but I just don't know how to preserve them from being overwritten by default values of the same or parent class.

Yet, another solution is combination of the above, like:

```
class A:
    p = 1
    def __init__(self, p=1, **kwargs):
        if p != 1: self.p = p
        ...
```

or using `dataclass`

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass
class A:
    p :int = 1

@dataclass
class B(A):
    p:int = 2
```

Just would like to know what is usual approach and consequences.

Comment: `if p: self.p = p` would not allow you to set a value of 0, or any other "falsy" value.  `if p is not None: ...` would be better.

Comment: If you want a specific default, why don't you use that as an actual default? Why do you need this for so many attributes/parameters that what you have is impractical? A class attribute *is not* an initializer default, so if you are looking for a "standard solution" we need to know for what actual problem.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, listing them on a class with default could be better for human viwer. Anyways, if I set them via __init__ default values, then it would be `1` for `b.p`

Comment: Well, you would override the default on B, of course. FWIW, I would strongly contest that a *class attribute* is more obvious as a *parameter default* than the very thing itself for the average Python programmer. Either way, it is still not clear to me what exactly you are trying to achieve. Is the class attribute supposed to be an *initialization* default or generally an *assignment* default? For example, what do you expect for `b.p = None` `print(b.p)`? Should the default be settable, i.e. what should/must be the effect of `B.p = 3`?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I added another example of Mamal and Bat, which is more close to our expectation from classes and their attributes. If there is no __init__ it seems setting class attributes and overriding them in child classes is a good approach, however, there are often an __init__ which makes us cautious about these assignments and the order of executions. I guess checking the condition in __init__ is a solution, just wondered if it's standard or not.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

If you really absolutely need both your class **and** your instances to have this attribute, **and also** want to use the class attribute as the default for an instance, I would say the correct way is like this:

```py
_sentinel = object()


class A:
    p = 1

    def __init__(self, p=_sentinel):
        if p is not _sentinel:
            self.p = p


class B(A):
    p = 2


a = A()
print(a.p)  # prints 1
b = B()
print(b.p)  # prints 2
b2 = B(p=None)
print(b2.p)  # prints None
```

The sentinel object is for when you do want to be able to pass `None` to the constructor for whatever reason. Since we compare *identity* in the `__init__` method, it is (practically) guaranteed that **if** any value is passed, it will be assigned to the instance attribute, even if that value is `None`.

**Original answer:**

The problem seems to stem from a misunderstanding of how (class-)attribute work in Python.

When you do this:

```py
class A:
    p = 1
```

You define a class attribute. Instances of that class will automatically have that same attribute upon initialization, **unless** you overwrite it, which is exactly what you do here:

```py
    def __init__(self, p=None, **kwargs):
        self.p = p
```

This overwrites the **instance's** attribute `.p` with the value `p` it receives in the `__init__` method. In this case, since you defined a default value `None` and called the constructor without passing an argument, that is what was assigned to the instance's attribute.

If you want, you can simply omit the `self.p` assignment in the constructor. Then your instances will have the class' default upon initialization.

**EDIT:**

Depending on how you want to handle it, you can simply assign the value after initialization. But I doubt that is what you want. You probably don't need class attributes at all. Instead you may just want to define the default values in your `__init__` method signature and assign them there.

If you **really** need that class attribute as well, you can do what you did, but more precisely by testing for `if p is not None:`.

Comment: Yes but what if you do want to override the value? This doesn't answer the question. It seems the OP wants to be able to pass a value to override or if `None` was passed, to take the class' value

Comment: i guess use `__new__` method and check there p is given or not and then there one can assign the value

Comment: @Tomerikoo Fair enough. Maybe I assumed too much. I updated my answer.

Comment: Good point about not needing to put default values to class, is idiomatic to have them in `__init__` where can deal with defaults and possible override. `__new__` is not necessary for this.

Comment: thanks, I added more clarification about my usage in the question. I mainly like to introduce child classes which override parrent attributes. but at the same time I want them to keep this values from being overwirtten by default values of init.

Comment: @Ahmad I addressed the issue of passing `None` to the init method in my updated answer.

Comment: Yet, there is another solution I added. That is checking the input of init against default value.

Answer (score 1):

I would set the default value of the `p` argument to the value that you want:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, p=1, **kwargs):
        self.p = p

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, p=2, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(p, **kwargs)

a = A()
print(a.p)
b = B()
print(b.p)
```

Then from the constructor of `B` you can call the one from `A` by using `super().__init__`

Answer (score -1):

You can use class properties from the class:

```
class A:
    p = 1

class B(A):
    p = 2

a = A()
print(a.p)
b = B()
print(b.p)
```

prints 1 and 2, like you wanted.

It is clearer to access them from the class directly, though:

```
print(A.p)
print(B.p)
```

You can set the instance one, without changing what is associated in the class.

```
class B(A):
    def change(self, x):
        self.p = x

b.change(3)
print(B.p) #2
print(b.p) #3
```

Comment: How does that answer the question? Where is the `__init__`? How will you set a new value to `p` or use the class attribute as a default? What is `change`?

Comment: The question does not ask about changing things at init, it asks how classes would preserve attributes. I copy-pasted from replit and missed the change() method first, that answers your question, i.e. shows how to change the instance attr, and have the class attr as default for the instance.